# Python-Rodeo in Ubuntu 14: Is there a correct way to install Rodeo without killing the instalation of Spyder?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, rodeo

I installed Rodeo using :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev    
sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev    
sudo pip install -U rodeo    
sudo pip install slugify    
sudo pip install ipykernel
```

It worked however, the spyder stopped working (it just didnt start).

I removed everything and rodeo started working again.

Is it possible to install rodeo without killing the previous installation of Spyder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. Install virtualenv, and virtualenv-wrapper, and you can install each IDE in his own Isolated environment.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install virtualenv
# optional 
# pip install virtualenvwarpper
```

Now you can create an isolated virtual environment where each python package has each own libraries and interpreter. See the [documentation for virtualenv here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Once you are comfortable with virtualenv, I highly recommend using virtualenvwrapper.